# CiviDiscount automatic problem

Tags: cividiscount

Is this an acceptable config for an automatic discount for students?

http://d46.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/cividiscount?reset=1

(screenshots below)

When I go to view the discount, the Automatic section is empty.  On my own sites I can't get the automatic discount to apply when I view an event page that satisfies the criteria.  I've seen issues like this that are marked closed on github from May. https://github.com/dlobo/org.civicrm.module.cividiscount/pull/98.  I've tried the current git version and have the same issues.

So I think it's more likely that my configuration is wrong since the view of the discount shows the Automatic Discount field to be empty.

Can someone look this over and tell me if there's an error?

[[image]
[[image]]

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

On the demo, I'm able to get the automatic discount to work. But also see the Automatic Discount as empty. See attached.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Ahh, but the issue is for the logged in user, not the civi-admin. We're not able to test this on the demo site unfortunately.  It's for events that have online registrations enabled.....sorry I left that out.  And thanks.

Comment: Peter, sorry for the delayed response.... Automatic discounts work for logged in users too. I have just verified on a local sandbox. A non-admin logged in user with a membership is seeing an automatic discount on a live registration page.

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, it was not an acceptable config.  Removing 'country' made the auto-discount work.